# Flutter telling me I have int? in my model file when I don't

Tags: flutter, variables, dart-null-safety

This is my model file:

```
final String shopTable = 'shop';

class ShopFields {
  static final String id = 'id';
  static final String item = 'item';
  static final String done = 'done';
  static final List<String> allFields = [id, item, done];
}

class Shop {
  final int id;
  final String item;
  bool done;

  Shop({
    required this.id,
    required this.item,
    this.done = false,
  });

  Map<String, Object?> toJson() => {
        ShopFields.id: id,
        ShopFields.item: item,
        ShopFields.done: done ? 1 : 0,
      };

  static Shop fromJson(Map<String, Object?> json) => Shop(
        id: json[ShopFields.id] as int,
        item: json[ShopFields.item] as String,
        done: json[ShopFields.done] == 1 ? true : false,
      );
}
```

I am getting an error that a type int? can't be assigned to a parameter type int but I don't have a type int?

ANy help would be appreciated.

Comment: You have id as an int in `Shop` but you try to assign it to string id in `ShopFields`. You have to keep it as int or parse to string.

Comment: There is an int inside your shop class.

Answer (score 0):

change the line below

```
id: json[ShopFields.id] as int,
```

to

```
id: int.parse(json[ShopFields.id]),
```